# PHP use symlink to connect on right database

Tags: php, database, apache, ssl, symlink

I have multiple databases (with same schema) used by multiple users. Each user has his own database. Some data of these databases need to be accessible by the public.

First I thought my structure like that: To access the database of user2, I connect to `http://user2.mysite.com/public`. If I want to see datas of user8, I connect to `http://user8.mysite.com/public`. It works great, but if I want a SSL I need a wildcard certificate, cheaper than a standard certificate.

Someone told me symbolic link can help me.

So I created another domain name and I would like that when someone connect on `mysite.com/user1` he can see database of user1, if I go on `mysite.com/user9` I connect to database of user9 to see public datas.

Someone told me I can create a symbolic link (`mysite.com/user1`) and in it I can put a config file with parameters to connect to the database of user1. I look for this but I can't find anything in docs.

Do you have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean with "database" that cannot be done in pure PHP and requires that complex setup?